# LINQ Group By if an object has x number of properties, then select on each group

Tags: c#, linq

I have some experience with LINQ but writing this query is proving to be a bit above my head.

Excuse my pseudo-code...

```
class Person{
Collection<Communications> {get;set}
}

class Communication{
Collection<PersonSender> {get;set;}
Collection<BuildingSender> {get;set;}
}

class PersonSender{
Collection<Posts> {get;set}
}

class BuildingSender{
Collection<Posts> {get;set}
}
```

**What I want to accomplish:** Group the `Communication` collection on whether it contains an instance of `PersonSender` or `BuildingSender` when those instances have a `Post` instance themselves.

Then I want to perform a select query on each group of `Collection` objects so I can return an `IEnumerable` collection of another object `Package` that is created in the select statement using each `Collection`'s properties. **The key here is that I need to perform a seperate select statement on each group returned**

**This is what I've got for the actual query so far**

```
m.Communications.GroupBy(x => 
new {fromMember = (x.PersonSender.Any() && x.Posts.Any()), 
     fromBuilding = (x.BuildingSender.Any() && x.Posts.Any())})
    .Select(u => new Package(u.PersonSender.First().Member,u.Posts.First()));
```

However I'm pretty sure this doesn't compile and it doesn't offer me the multiple select statements I need.

Is GroupBy the right way to go about this? Is it even possible?

**UPDATE:** Per @Hogan I have been able to hack together a work solution. Let me try to clear up what I was trying to do though, my original question wasn't very clear...

This code is part of the class `PackageFactory` . Each method in this class can be invoked by a Controller in my application asking for a set of `Package` objects. The `Package` accepts several types of `IEntity` objects as parameters and wraps the content that is associated with the relationships the `IEntity` objects have into an interface that any other controller displaying information on my application can read. TLDR `Package` is a glorified Adapter pattern design object.

Each method in `PackageFactory` has the job of querying the `Communication` repository, finding the relevant `Communication` objects with the right set of properties, and then passing the subset of objects(that are properties of the `Communication` object) to the a new `Package` instance to be wrapped before returning the whole set of `Package` objects to the controller so they can be rendered on a page.

In the case of the method I am writing for this question the user `m` has a collection of `Communication` objects where each `Communication` comes from an `IEntity` object(either `PersonSender` or `BuildingSender`) that was directed at the user `m` . My query was an attempt to segregate the `Communication` objects into two sets where one contains all `Communication` where `PeronSender` exists and one where `BuildingSender` exists. This way my method knows which group gets passed to their respective `Package` type.

My logic for trying to use GroupBy was that I would rather make the query as generic as possible so that I can expand to more sets later AND/OR increase the performance of the method by not having to call many seperate queries and then join them all. However it seems like specifying distinct select queries on each group is not a possibility.

@Hogan 's answer is close to what I want to be able to do.

**Hogan's Answer**

```
var result =
m.comm.SelectMany(x => x.person).Where(x => x.posts.Any()).Select(new () { x.name, x.posts})
.Union(m.comm.SelectMany(x=> x.building).Where(x => x.posts.Any()).Select(new () {x.name, x.posts}));
```

**Modified Answer**

This is what works:

```
return m.Communications.Where(x => x.SendingPerson.Any() && x.Posts.Any()).Select(u => 
new PostPackage(u.SendingPerson.First().Member,m,u.Posts.First()))
.Union(m.Communications.Where(x=> x.BuildingSender.Any() && x.Posts.Any()).Select(u => 
new PostPackage(u.BuildingSender.First().Building,m,u.Posts.First())));
```

Not exactly the same -- My head was a bit foggy when I wrote this question yesterday.

Comment: You don't define the Attribute names in your code.

Comment: yes, all your classes are some kind of signature? Where are Properties names?

Comment: What is the so-called `separate select statement on each group returned`? As I understand, that means, if you have 100 hundreds of groups, you will need 100 different selects?

Comment: @KingKing - I think he was asking for SelectMany -- see my answer now that I'm done.

Comment: @Hogan I hope so, however I'm still not sure about what he wants.

Comment: @MattFoxxDuncan - The only thing that is unclear in your answer is that both sending person and building sender are using the same Posts list.  Shouldn't the x.Posts.Any() be somehow tied to to the sender (Person or building)?

Comment: @Hogan - Ah but they aren't! This may be bad design on my part but the senders are mutually exclusive in my business logic. I either have a buildingsender OR a personsender tied to a communication object -- never both. I guess I could have two different types of Communication objects but so many of their other properties/interactions are so similar it's not worth duplicating 75% of the code. I've been very thorough in my BL to make sure the two "types" are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @MattFoxxDuncan - Got it.  Now your code makes perfect sense.  It was `Union` you needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the key is the SelectMany not GroupBy -- This will "flatten" a sub-lists.  As I've shown below:

With

```
class Person{
  Collection<Communications> comm {get; set;}
}

class Communication{
  Collection<PersonSender> person {get; set;}
  Collection<BuildingSender> building {get; set;}
}

class PersonSender{
  string name {get; set; }
  Collection<Posts> posts {get; set;}
}

class BuildingSender{
  string name {get; set; }
  Collection<Posts> posts {get; set;}
}
```

given that m is a person:

```
var result =
   m.comm.SelectMany(x => x.person).Where(x => x.posts.Any()).Select(new () { x.name, x.posts})
 .Union(m.comm.SelectMany(x=> x.building).Where(x => x.posts.Any()).Select(new () {x.name, x.posts}));
```

Comment: Yes! This is much closer to what I was trying to do. My question wasn't as clear as it should have been but you cut through my murky explanation. Thanks! I'll add an update to my question clearing up what I meant